# ASP.net Usercontrol Base and child how to initialize Base controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

HI ,

1.create Base usercontrol which contains a label and sets text of it to be "test1" this is set in the ascx page.
   2.Create a user control which inherits from the base user control.
   3. Now on the page load of the child control i try to do:

protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //Exception thrown by this as Label1 is null
        this.Label1.Text = "sasasas";

}

However i  get an exception because the Label1 is null.

Can aonyone tell me how to initialize the base controls controls when the child control is created?????

thanks
Niall

Comment: Try not to do it this way. Expose a property in the base user control, set that property in the child control. The base user control can then see if it's set, then set the text accordingly.

Comment: That's rpm I would Have given you a score had you added answer below. Cheers niall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RPM1984 commented: do not inherit from your Webusercontrol but nest it inside of your other Usercontrol. When you have exposed a Control(f.e. your Label or its Text property) as property in the "parent"-UC, you can access it from your "child"-UC.

Besides, always use [LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.loadcontrol.aspx) to initialize an dynamically added Usercontrol and not the constructor (what might be the cause that the Textbox is NULL).

Comment: Thanks for that. Ya I could have done that but because I wanted inheritance based control to enforce required methods etc  I modified my base control to not be a user control but to inherit from system.we.ui.usercontrol instead.